# How would I keep an h1 tag and a p tag next to this form? (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [form on my website](http://www.invisional.com/contactus.html). And I am trying to put text on the right side of it. So like one `h1` tag and some paragraphs, I have already tried:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
        <h1 class="text-right">Header</h1>
        <form action="sent.php" method="post" title="contact" lang="en">
            <p>Your Name:</p> <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
              <span class="add-on">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>
              </span>
              <input class="span2" name="name" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and

```
<div class="hero-unit">
        <h1 class="text-right" style="display: inline-block;">Header</h1>
        <form action="sent.php" method="post" title="contact" lang="en">
            <p>Your Name:</p> <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
              <span class="add-on">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>
              </span>
              <input class="span2" name="name" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Does anyone have advice for me?

Comment: Did you try `float:left;` on both elements?

Comment: Is this an incomplete snippet? Didn't see your closing `</form>` tag anywhere.

Comment: I know, I was just showing the first part of my code, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), so you just need to add a `row` class to the container, a `span4` class to the form and a new `<div>` with text and `span8` class below the form:

```
<div class="hero-unit" class="row">
  <form ... class="span4">
    ...
  </form>

  <div class="span8">
    <h2>On the Origin of Species</h2>
    <p>On the Origin of Species, published on 24 November 1859, is a work of scientific literature by Charles Darwin which is considered to be the foundation of evolutionary biology.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text will automatically appear at the right when browser window is wide enough.

See the demo of the result: http://jsbin.com/imiciv/1

For more information on Bootstrap grid system, read the documentation:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Answer (score 0):

To place a `p` or `h1` to the right of the form, it would be easiest to place the tags below the close of the `form`. Then `float` the the `form` and `h1` to the `left`.

HTML:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <form action="sent.php" method="post" title="contact" lang="en">
        ...
    </form>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
form, h1, p {
    float: left;
}
```

### JS Fiddle Example

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution is poor: http://jsfiddle.net/g5SQw/1/ . It could be fixed by applying width to the form and margin-left to a div next to the form (you really should use a container). But the matter is that this website is using Bootstrap, so it's much simplier to use its classes. This will also make the form responsive.

Comment: @lolmaus: My answer was not bootstrap-specific; I was giving him an example of how it can be done given the code snippet he provided.